# Python C Module - Malloc fails in specific version of Python

Tags: python, c, memory-management, cpython

I'm writing a Python module to perform IO on a O_DIRECT context. One of the limitations of O_DIRECT is you must read into a buffer aligned on a 4096 byte boundary for 2.4 and 2.5 kernels, and 2.6 and up will accept any multiple of 512.

The obvious memory allocation candidate for this is `posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size)`

In my code, I allocate an area like so:

```c
char *buffer = NULL;

int mem_ret = posix_memalign((void**)&buffer, alignment, size);

if (!buffer) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    return NULL;
}

/* I do some stuff here */

free(buffer);
```

When I compile and import the module with python3.2, this (and the rest of the unshown module) work fine.

When I attempt the same with python2.7 (I'd like to preserve compatibility) it throws the PyErr_NoMemory exception, and `mem_ret == ENOMEM`, indicating it was unable to allocate.

Why would the version of Python I compile against affect how posix_memalign operates?

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Compiler: Clang + GCC Show same behaviour

**UPDATE**

I now have a working piece of code, thanks to user694733
However the fact that it works has me even more confused:

```c
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
char *buffer = NULL;

int mem_ret = posix_memalign((void**)&buffer, alignment, count);
#else
void *mem = NULL;

int mem_ret = posix_memalign(&mem, alignment, count);

char *buffer = (char*)mem;
#endif
```

Can anyone explain why the **incorrect** first block works under Python3, but not 2.7, and more importantly why the **correct** second block does not work under Python3?

**UPDATE 2**

The plot thickens, having settled on the correct form of the code below, I tested on 4 different version of Python.

```c
void *mem = NULL;

int mem_ret = posix_memalign(&mem, alignment, count);

char *buffer = (char*)mem;

if (!buffer) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    return NULL;
}

/* Do stuff with buffer */

free(buffer);
```

Under **Python 2.7**: This code operates as expected.
Under **Python 3.1**: This code operates as expected.
Under **Python 3.2**: This code generates `mem_ret == ENOMEM` and returns NULL for `buffer`
Under **Python 3.3**: This code operates as expected.

The Python versions not included in the Ubuntu repositories were installed from the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes

If the version tagged Python binaries are to be believed, the versions I have installed are:

```
python2.7 
python3.1
python3.2mu (--with-pymalloc --with-wide-unicode)
python3.3m (--with-pymalloc)
```

Could the use of the wide-unicode flag in the default Python3 distribution be causing this error? If so, how is this happening?

For clarity, the `ENOMEM` failure to allocate will occur with any variant of `malloc()`, even something as simple as `malloc(512)`.

Comment: Note that casting `char**` to `void**` is not valid. Pointers might have different sizes. Use `void *buffer = NULL;`, and later you can assign it to `char*` if you need byte access.

Comment: Have you tried printing `size` and `alignment` to see if they make sense? Perhaps they're changed as a side-effect of some UB elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Even if I hardcode those params and call a literal posix_memalign(buffer, 512, 512) it still fails to allocate under 2.7

Comment: Python 3.3 is AFAIK always built as if you had defined `--with-wide-unicode`.

Comment: @filmor

If we look at the ancient history that is:
http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-pymalloc.html

In particular, `In 2.3, pymalloc has had further enhancements and is now enabled by default`

This would indicate that PyMalloc should be built into 2.7 and 3.1, yet they lack the `m` tag, is this an inconsistency or are those versions genuinely built without it? The 2.7 on my machine is the version that ships with Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: A workaround could be to build a shared library and interface it with [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.8/) or ctypes

Comment: can you paste a self-contained, full .c file ? And the exact compilation flags you're using ?

Comment: Why not anonymous `mmap`? it's aligned by default and should not has side effect wrt. "system" memory allocator (i.e. libc/python they are different)

Answer (score 1):

For a quick work-around, stick to `mmap` instead of `malloc+memalign`

Answer (score 0):

posix_memalign may not be the same body of code in one compilation environment as another. You could easily imagine that Python 3 would use [different feature test](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros) macros to Python 2. That could mean it ends up running different code.

You might have a look at the symbols that are used... often times the output of ldd or nm will have mangled names that indicate what version is actually being used.

Additionally, what does an strace show of the allocation system call? I find that's a good way of seeing if the arguments passed in are incorrect, which can be a reason for getting ENOMEM.