# Why is char** (or any T**) to void** cast invalid?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

In the first comment to [Python C Module - Malloc fails in specific version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21458818/761090), @user694733 mentions that casting `char**` to `void**` is not valid. I read [Invalid conversion from Foo** to void** - why is implicit type conversion allowed to void* but not to void**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938860/invalid-conversion-from-foo-to-void-why-is-implicit-type-conversion-allowe) and http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html but there is a reference to standard, but no real example, in which case this might be incorrect, leading to errores . Thinking of e.g. `void**` to `double**` or vice versa, is there a case where it can go wrong? Why (technically, not just because it is UB)?

Comment: Please clearly state the problem, instead of forcing anyone willing to solve your request, reading 2-3 additional posts.

Comment: Casting and the behaviour of `void*` are not the same in C and C++. Please pick one.

Comment: Firstly, the term "casting" in C and C++ refers to an *explicit cast*. Explicit cast from `T **` to `void **` is generally *valid*.  Secondly, the potential problem with the corresponding conversion has exactly the same underlying structure as the `T ** -> const T **` conversion described in the well-known FAQ entry: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

Comment: The cast is not invalid; any object pointer type may be cast to any other object pointer type, and there is only UB if there is an alignment error , which is unlikely in this case (most systems have all pointers with the same alignment requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but there is a reference to standard, but no real example, in which case this might be incorrect, leading to errors

This is not accurate. Page http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html which you mentioned points to another page http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html which contains an example of machines with different pointer sizes for different types:

> The Eclipse MV series from Data General has three architecturally supported pointer formats (word, byte, and bit pointers), two of which are used by C compilers: byte pointers for char * and void *, and word pointers for everything else. For historical reasons during the evolution of the 32-bit MV line from the 16-bit Nova line, word pointers and byte pointers had the offset, indirection, and ring protection bits in different places in the word. Passing a mismatched pointer format to a function resulted in protection faults. Eventually, the MV C compiler added many compatibility options to try to deal with code that had pointer type mismatch errors.

Comment: Well, how would one create a function receiving a double pointer of generic type as an argument ?

Comment: @APJo As it is said here http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html, there is no problem in having a function with `void**` argument, but such a function should actually know the underlying pointer type when it reads data from that double-pointer. Maybe this information can be passed as a separate argument or by other means.

Comment: I am, at the moment, making a `int safe_malloc(void** toalloc, size_t bytes)` - and it appears to work directly too, though at the moment I use it only for `char *`s - are their serious issues with this is practise ?

Answer (score 11):

If that was allowed, it would create a loop hole in the type system:

```
T* ptr;
void **vptr = &ptr; // &ptr is of type T**
int value;
*vptr = &value;     // &value is int*, can be converted to void*
```

At this point, `ptr`, which is according to the type system a pointer to `T`, is pointing to `value` that is an `int`.  While the language allows you to circumvent the type system, you have to explicitly request it. Implicit conversions are designed to avoid this type of issues.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest practical problem is with multiple inheritance. When you use a pointer to a class with multiple base classes, the actual value of the pointer will depend on the type of the pointer, and the compiler inserts fix-up code to adjust it when you assign from one pointer type to another. When you have a pointer to the pointer, the compiler no longer has the opportunity to do those fixups, so the operation is disallowed by the standard.