# Casting Structs With Void Pointers into Structs With Typed Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers

Short version:

Suppose I have two structs:

```
struct charPtrWithLen
{
 size_t len;
 char * charPtr;
}

struct voidPtrWithLen
{
 size_t len;
 void * voidPtr;
}
```

Is there a way to cast voidPtrWithLen into charPtrWithLen and vice-versa, or even better, implicitly convert one into the other, much the same way that a char * and a void * can be readily cast and implicitly converted between each other?

Put another way:

I am trying to write all my C so that all pointers to arrays bring their size information with them. I am also trying to write generic functions using void pointers where applicable to keep operations which are essentially identical, well, identical. I am looking for a way to pass the typed-pointer-containing 'sized-array' structs into the generic functions taking void-pointer-containing 'sized-array' arguments.

Long version, with involved example:

So, void pointers are wonderfully flexible, so I can do this:

```
int foo(void * ptr, size_t dataLen);
/* ... */
char * c;
size_t c_n;
/* ... */
foo(c, c_n);
/* ... */
int * i;
size_t i_n;
/* ... */
foo(i, i_n);
```

But since the pattern of "pointer to arbitrary length array, plus size there-of" is so common, suppose at some point I get tired of specifying my various functions in terms of pairs of arguments, pointer and length, and instead I start to code with such pairs encapsulated in a struct instead:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t v_n;
    void * v;
}
pointerWithSize;
/* ... */
int foo(pointerWithSize);
```

So far so good. I can always assign my "char * c" or "int * i" into the pointerWithSize's "void * v" with minimal difficulty. But when you do this long enough, using the same pattern, you run into the following problem: Soon enough you have a bunch of general functions which work with the data agnostically, and are thus happy to take void pointers, for example things like:

```
pointerWithSize combinePointersWithSize(pointerWithSize p1, pointerWithSize p2);
int readFromStream(FILE * readFromHere, pointerWithSize * readIntoHere);
```

But you also end up with functions which are inherently intended for specific data types:

```
size_t countOccurancesOfChar(pointerWithSize str, char c);
int summate(pointerWithSize integers);
```

And then you end up with the annoyance of having to do casts inside the latter category of functions. E.g. you end up with stuff like this:
    /* This inside countOccurancesOfChar */
    if(((char * )str.m)[i] == c) {
    /* ..or this inside summate: */
    sum += ((int * )integers.m)[i];

So you get to a point where you have a lot of functions which operate specifically on "strings with size", and in all of those cases, you don't want to have to much around with void pointers. So instead, in those cases you start doing stuff like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t v_n;
    char * v;
}
stringWithSize;
/* ... */
size_t countOccurancesOfChar(stringWithSize str, char c);
int parseFormatting(stringWithSize str, struct someFormat_t foo);
```

Which is great, because now all the string related code doesn't need to be cluttered with casts. BUT, now I can't use my wonderful generic function combinePointersWithSize to concatenate my strings contained within the stringWithSize, in a way that's as syntactically clean, as I could if I was still writing my functions in terms of two separate arguments for each pointer-and-size pair.

To finish up the illustration:

```
pointerWithSize combinePointersWithSize(pointerWithSize p1, pointerWithSize p2);
void * combineAlternative(void * p1, size_t p_n1, void * p2);
/* ... */
stringWithSize a, b, c;
/* ... */
/* This doesn't work, incompatible types: */
c = combinePointersWithSize(a, b);
/* But this works, because char * can be passed into void * parameter. */
c.v_n = a.v_n + b.v_n;
c.v = combineAlternative(a.v, a.v_n, b.v, b.v_n); /* Works fine. */
```

Possible Solutions I've Considered:

1: Don't write my functions with those structs as arguments, instead write them with individual pair arguments. But this is a big part of what I want to avoid in the first place - I like the 'cleanness' and clarity of intent that having a size_t and a pointer bundled in one struct represents.

2: Do something like this:

```
stringWithSize a, b, c;
/* ... */
pointerWithSize d;
d = combinePointersWithSize((pointerWithSize){.v=a.v, .v_n=a.v_n}, (pointerWithSize){.v=b.v, .v_n=b.v_n})
/* and then do either this: */
c.v = d.v;
c.v_n = d.v_n;
foo(c);
/* ..or this: */
foo((stringWithSize){.v=d.v, .v_n=d.v_n});
```

..but I think most would agree, this is also as bad or worse as the original problem of casting within the library functions. On the surface it looks worse, because it offloads the casting burden to the client code instead of library code which can hopefully be fairly stable after being implemented/completed (incl. testing/etc). On the other hand, if you did keep every function defined in terms of the void * containing pointerWithSize, you could end up forcing similar casts to the kind you're doing inside your own functions, elsewhere in their code, and worse, you're losing the advantage of the compiler yelling at you, because now the code is carrying everything within the same pointerWithSize struct.

I'm also concerned about how many compilers out there have the ability to optimize the first of the two variants of this solution away (where 'd' servers as merely a temporary result holder.

3: Union-of-pointers. Instead of my prior pointerWithSize example, I would do:

```
typedef union
{
    void * void;
    char * char;
    int * int;
    /* ...and so on... */
}
rainbowPointer;

typedef struct
{
    size_t v_n;
    rainbowPointer v;
}
pointerWithSize;
```

At first glance this is almost good enough. However, I very frequently end up wanting to store arrays of some struct which is specific to the program I'm working on inside this "pointer with size" construct, and in those cases, a predefined union of pointer types would be useless to me, I'd still be right back at this problem.

4: I could write wrapper functions for each permuted pointer type. I could EVEN write function-like macros to define each of these pointer-with-size struct types, which would in the same swoop generate the wrapper functions. For example:

```
#define pointerWithSizeDef(T, name) \
typedef struct \
{ \
    size_t v_n; \
    T * v;
} \
name; \
foo_ ## name (name p1) \
{ \
    /* generic function code defined in macro */ \
    /* Or something like this: */ \
    foo((pointerWithSize){.v=p1.v, .v_n=p1.v_n});
};
/* Then, stuff like this: */
pointerWithSizeDef(char, stringWithSize)
```

My intuition is that sooner or later this method would become unwieldy.

5: If there is a mechanism with no performance impact, but which is unappealing otherwise, I could write my generic functions as function-like macros, which in turn invoke the underlying actual function:

```
int foo_actual(void * v, size_t v_n);
#define foo(p) \
foo_actual(p.v, p.v_n);
```

..or even something like this, to replace casting syntax:

```
#define castToPointerWithSize(p) \
((pointerWithSize){.v=p.v, .v_n=p.v_n})
/* ... */
stringWithSize a;
foo(castToPointerWithSize(a));
```

But as these examples for possible-solution-#5 show, I can't actually think of a way to do this that wouldn't quickly become a possible problem (e.g. if someone wanted to place a function call which returned a pointerWithSize in place of 'p' in the above examples - you'd be running the function twice, and it wouldn't be at all obvious from the code.

So I don't think any of the solutions I've thought of are really sufficient for my usecase, so I'm hoping some of you know of some C syntax or mechanism I could take advantage of here to make it easy to cast/"cast" between two structs which are identical save for the pointer type of one of their members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, any kind of "actual" casting isn't going to be allowed per the letter of the standard, because C [makes no guarantee at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29978561/1366431) that all pointers have the same format. A cast from some arbitrary pointer type to a void pointer is allowed to involve a conversion of representation (that gets reversed when you cast it back in order to access the data), including possibly to a different size of pointer or a pointer existing in a separate address space. So a simple reinterpretation of a bit pattern to change pointer type is not safe; `void*`'s bit pattern isn't guaranteed to mean anything in particular, and the bit patterns of other types aren't guaranteed to be related in any particular way. (How many systems actually take advantage of this, I have no idea.)

Since the explicit conversion between `void*` and other types has to exist somewhere, using whole-value conversion is probably the safest idea. What you could do is define a macro to quickly and easily generate "cast functions" for you, e.g.:

```
#define GEN_CAST(NAME, FROM_TYPE, TO_TYPE)     \
  static inline TO_TYPE NAME(FROM_TYPE from) { \
    return (TO_TYPE){ .v=p.v, .v_n=p.v_n };    \
  }

GEN_CAST(s_to_v, stringWithSize, pointerWithSize)
GEN_CAST(v_to_s, pointerWithSize, stringWithSize)
```

...that you can then use in place of the cast operator in expressions:

```
stringWithSize a, b, c;
pointerWithSize d;
d = combinePointersWithSize(s_to_v(a), s_to_v(b));
foo(v_to_s(d));
```

A good compiler should recognise that on common platforms the conversion function is an identity operation, and remove it entirely.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to cast one to another by converting one to a pointer, casting it to a pointer of the other type, and dereferencing it. This will work in reverse too.

```
struct charPtrWithLen
{
 size_t len;
 char * charPtr;
};

struct voidPtrWithLen
{
 size_t len;
 void * voidPtr;
};

int main() {
    struct charPtrWithLen cpwl = {.len = 6, .charPtr = "Hello"};

    struct voidPtrWithLen vpwl = *(struct voidPtrWithLen *)&cpwl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note this will only work as long as the struct layout is the same for both structs.

Comment: But only because one is `void*` and the other is `char*`. If the other would a pointer to some other type, this isn't portable.